# How to treat semver when property becomes obsolete

Tags: javascript, css, semantic-versioning

We're using semver for our CSS libraries, making sure to follow the offical [guidelines](https://semver.org/) on how to version them.

However, whenever we make a class (or in the case of JS - a property or argument) obsolete - what should we do? The client can remove it from its markup / function calls, but doesn't have to, really.

What would be the correct version?

- A patch, because you don't really have to do anything as a consumer?
- A minor, because you CAN clean up your code?
- A major even, becase the API changed, albeit an optional one, but the consumer SHOULD clean up its code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of my understanding of your case you should mark the obsolete class as `deprecated` and this would lead to an incrementation of the minor version as written under point 7:

> 7. Minor version Y (x.Y.z | x > 0) MUST be incremented if new, backwards compatible functionality is introduced to the public API. **It MUST be incremented if any public API functionality is marked as deprecated.** It MAY be incremented if substantial new functionality or improvements are introduced within the private code. It MAY include patch level changes. Patch version MUST be reset to 0 when minor version is incremented.